# Multiple group queries using sum & count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So for the given model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: faction_armories
#
#  id           :bigint           not null, primary key
#  action       :string
#  qty          :integer
#  tid          :string
#  timestamp    :datetime
#  user_name    :string
#  created_at   :datetime         not null
#  updated_at   :datetime         not null
#  faction_id   :integer
#  item_id :integer
#  user_id      :integer
#
```

I'm attempting to group user_name, action, and item_id, and add up all the qty's from each entry. For example

```
action="used","user_name"="me","qty"=5,"item_id"=4
action="used","user_name"="me","qty"=10,"item_id"=4
```

Should return a hash that identifies that me - used item 4 - 15 times.

Currently, I'm running two queries but still, the data is not coming through correctly, any input would be greatly appreciated

```
@news = FactionArmory.where(faction_id: current_user.faction_id).order(user_name: :asc).where("timestamp >= ?", params["report_start"]).where("timestamp <= ?", params["report_end"]).includes([:item]).group("user_name", "action", "item_id").count
@qty = FactionArmory.where(faction_id: current_user.faction_id).order(user_name: :asc).where("timestamp >= ?", params["report_start"]).where("timestamp <= ?", params["report_end"]).includes([:item]).group("user_name", "action", "item_id").sum(:qty)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `select` or `pluck` to get multiple calculations in one query

```
FactionArmory
  .group("user_name", "action", "item_id")
  .pluck("user_name", "action", "item_id", "count(distinct faction_armories.id) as count", "sum(qty) as qty_sum")
```

Comment: Nice, I totally forgot that you can use sql function in pluck